# What are the dependencies of a React Native Android build that are subject to change?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native app that I build for both iOS and Android. Nothing changes in the code or our CI system, but for some reason, the Android build periodically stops working and I'll have to make some adjustments to the build.gradle in order to fix it.

The iOS build, on the other hand, has no problems as long as the version of Xcode stays the same.

I'm wondering what part of the Android build's dependencies are subject to change and how can I lock them to specific versions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to periodically update your app to keep up with security/bug fixes in the code you use. The operating system regularly gets updated and changes to Android or iOS may require you to update as well. You can't predict what these companies do.

By default, your packages/libraries do not update themselves. You'll have to add `^` at the beginning of their version number in package.json dependency list. That'll keep them updated to the latest minor version, as any major update would introduce breaking changes (which requires you to change some code.)

Comment: I'm aware of how to pin node modules to specific versions and a yarn.lock is present. 

The issue is that the Android dependencies change. For example, on 6/7/23 a new version of androidx.core library was released, androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha05. My build is now using this version instead of the version it was building with last month and my question is, how do I prevent this.